# Problems adding expected GIMP file to 'New' Context Menu

Tags: windows, context-menu, gimp

I am trying to add 'GIMP image' to Window 10's 'New' context menu, as discussed here -

**New Menu Demo:**

- [How to Add Other File Types to the New Item Menu in Windows 10’s File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/290500/how-to-add-other-file-types-to-the-new-item-menu-in-windows-10s-file-explorer/) - How-to-Geek (1/27/17)

This works for XML files (appears as 'XML Document'), but it won't work for my GIMP XCFs!

**My Attempt:**

- [Add File Type to New Menu Notes.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EPtMDB7lOVRgkKsdSywKUsSVTDv8wvn/view?usp=sharing)

How to get XCF to the 'New' context menu too?

Comment: The Google Drive link says "You need access". Can you upload the text file contents to somewhere else (e.g., PasteBin.com) instead?

Comment: hehe I was frustrated and moving too fast; link works now (alt - pastebin.com/u5cy1ALB)

Comment: A complete file association report for .XCF would be helpful. You can generate it using the [FileTypeDiag](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/filetypediag-dump-file-association-info/) tool. Then upload to GDrive/Pastebin and post us the link.

Comment: Here is my [.XCF report](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-K_r6WM9VfB-F67boTOXncf2n5udMYGe?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.XCF` file type's `(default)` value data is missing. Running the following command (from admin/elevated Command Prompt window) should fix the issue:

```
assoc .xcf=GIMP2.xcf
```

Assuming that the file `template.xcf` exists in the `Windows\ShellNew` folder.

[image]

Comment: oh my gosh - this works!!! easy, quick and complete this solved it and is working now

Comment: Thanks! I spent a long time at this, and learned much

Comment: Excellent. Glad that worked and thanks for the update! :)